# How I can filter out a value in my SQL query based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone please help me with the below issue that is driving me to madness lately:

I have a table with article numbers, the component used for that article and a change number.

One article should have one component but because of production issues sometimes it happens that it has an old and a new component. In this case a change number is present.

My real question is: How can I build a select query which filters all the articles + components where the change number is NULL, and only the new component for the articles where the change number is present.

```
Article:    Component:  Change Number:
00011873    01044541    NULL             -Not required in list
00011873    01040994    000000000001     -Should be present in list

00011875    01020151    NULL             -Should be present in list
00011881    01025465    NULL             -Should be present in list
00011883    01045066    NULL             -Should be present in list
```

I am only at beginner level with SQL databases and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What should be the result if there are more changes -- do you want all rows with changes, or only the row with the highest change number (thus guaranteeing that there is only one row per article)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all rows for an article where the change is not null and then `null` for the remaining articles, you can put this logic in the `where` clauses using `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.change_number is not null or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.article = t.article and
                        t2.change_number is not null
                 );
```

This is a SQL translation of the first part of this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works as I expect it to be. :) Now my hair can remain at my head. Your answear is greatly appreciated by me. And it's fairly easy to understand and interpret, no idea how I was unable to figure it out on my own.

Comment: I had to test it, because I was curious! I must say that the solution is brilliant and elegant. Tested here >> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eed14/4